# Issue with infinite horizontal scroll animation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a horizontally scrolling bar that advanced with a button click, and starts again after the last child is reached in pure javascript. It's also important that the duplicated divs are removed, since there might be 1000s of clicks and it would bloat the dom otherwise.

I have the bar working with the animation, but the infinite part does not quite work as intended.
I have tried two different approaches (see below) which both give two different, wrong results.
'myFunction' has the animation working but scrolls too far.
'myFunction2' has the scroll correct, but has no animation.

How could I get both of those things (scroll and animation) working at the same time?

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5bq1o4xh/5/

```js
  var slider = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  var currentPosition = 0;
  var elementWidth = 10;

window.myFunction = function() {
    if(currentPosition > 100 - (slider.childElementCount * elementWidth)) {
      currentPosition = currentPosition - elementWidth;
      slider.style.left = currentPosition + '%';
    } else {
        slider.innerHTML += slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[0].outerHTML;
        slider.removeChild(slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[0]);
        currentPosition = currentPosition - elementWidth;
        slider.style.left = currentPosition + '%';
    } 
}

window.myFunction2 = function() {
    if(currentPosition > 100 - (slider.childElementCount * elementWidth)) {
      currentPosition = currentPosition - elementWidth;
      slider.style.left = currentPosition + '%';
    } else {
        slider.innerHTML += slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[0].outerHTML;
        currentPosition = currentPosition + elementWidth;
        slider.style.left = currentPosition + '%';
        slider.removeChild(slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[0]);
        currentPosition = currentPosition - elementWidth;
        slider.style.left = currentPosition + '%';
    } 
}
```

```css
.brands-wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.brands-slide {
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.brands-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: medium;
  font-size: initial;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="brands-wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper" class="brands-slide">
    <div class="brands-brand">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      7
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      8
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      9
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      10
    </div><div class="brands-brand">
      11
    </div><div class="brands-brand">
      12
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button onclick="myFunction()">
Next
</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">
Next2
</button>
```

Please note that I am looking for a pure JS solution, no jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It need a little improvements here and there but it should do the trick :

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  var start = true;

window.myFunction = function() {
    let brand=slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[0];
    if(start)brand.style.marginLeft = '-10%';
    else{
      slider.appendChild(brand);
      brand.style.marginLeft = '0px';
      slider.getElementsByClassName('brands-brand')[0].style.marginLeft = '-10%';
    }
    start=false;
}
```

```css
.brands-wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.brands-slide {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.brands-brand {
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: medium;
  font-size: initial;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="brands-wrapper">
  <div id="wrapper" class="brands-slide">
    <div class="brands-brand">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      7
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      8
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      9
    </div>
    <div class="brands-brand">
      10
    </div><div class="brands-brand">
      11
    </div><div class="brands-brand">
      12
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button onclick="myFunction()">
Next
</button>
```

Basically I'm switching the transition to the brand, and each time you click the script it take the first shown element, shove it outside and if it's not the first call of the function, take the previous hidden element to the parent's end and reset it's css.

Comment: I really like this solution, there is just one issue, when you click the next button like crazy it starts to bug out with the animations. Do you think there is a way to solve this, maybe by adding an interval clear if the button is pressed while a animation is still running?

Comment: I thought about it since I dislike `setTimeOut` solutions. Here's something a little better without the drawback you mention ^^

Comment: Love your solution! Works like a charm and looks efficient!